# Laravel 8, Sanctum and Angular 8

Tags: angular, laravel, api, cors, laravel-sanctum

I have the subject environment in linux. I have made the configuration of cors.conf, session.conf, kernel:api with EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful, .env. All that is raccomanated in all documentation that i read.
Laravel in localhost:8000
Angular in localhost:4200

In particular:

Kernel.php:

```
'api' => [
      \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
      'throttle:api',
...
```

cors.php

```
'paths' => [
    'api/*',
    'login',
    'logout',
    'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

sanctum.php

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'localhost:4200,localhost,localhost:8000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:4200,127.0.0.1:8000')),
```

in .env

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost
```

In Angular when i get csrf-cookie respons is:

Bloccata richiesta multiorigine (cross-origin): il criterio di corrispondenza dell’origine non consente la lettura della risorsa remota da http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie. Motivo: richiesta CORS non riuscita.

this is my stack:

[image]

where am i wrong?
Thank's before.

Comment: csrf-collie request is loading okay with proper Allow Origin, what's returned for login? if you aren't able to check details of it's request then query it in postman and share the response

Comment: Yes, i know, but simply the returned cookie don't was saved in storage so in login reques miss X-CSRF-COOKIE

Comment: you are using withCredentials so technically the cookie should be sent, as for using cookie in API, I will suggest move to JWT and use the `api` routes of Laravel. Sending request to `web` routes is for web pages.

Answer (score -1):

You request is being blocked due to violation of Cross Origin Resource Sharing or CORS for short.

This issue arises when you make a request from domain A to domain B. In this case, as you are using localhost, I suppose you are making requests from ng server @ `localhost:4200` to `localhost:8000`, viz Laravel Server.

To solve it, you need to add CORS headers in responses from your Laravel server i.e `localhost:8000`. In simple cases, you can add this header in your response `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

The `*` means that the server is willing to respond to request from any domain. This is a serious security concern in Production so you should always specify your exact domains which should be allowed for CORS e.g:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200`

There are multiple ways to do it. For developmental purposes, you can use a CORS plugin such as `CORS everywhere` for FireFox.

For development server, you can also add CORS headers either in web server or via Laravel. An easy way to use `laravel-cors` package from [here](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors)

You can also do further readings on CORS on [Mozilla Site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Thanks, but is no sufficient set laravel cors config file? in many tutorial this work. I've configured firefox plugin Moesif CORS, but not work.

Comment: Laravel CORS config is sufficient but then you need to validate as well whether your headers are correct and properly sent to server. Can you share request and response headers?

Comment: this i request:  
GET /sanctum/csrf-cookie undefined
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:4200/corporate/session/login 

The response in blocked.

Comment: This in Chrome:
`Request URL: http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhoat:4200
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 05 Nov 2020 15:02:21 GMT
Date: Thu, 05 Nov 2020 15:02:21 GMT
Host: localhost:8000
phpdebugbar-id: Xf3c98679b8e84bb0000e3754630791c8
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InNFSGxrZjhZUklCaTJ2dStvVFo5d2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibHBCbTk4S...

Comment: `Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6I.....zov-2020 17:02:21 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=.localhost; httponly; samesite=lax
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.12
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8000
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/corporate/session/login
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36`

Comment: i alredy use laravel-cors

Comment: You need to specify protocol here ` Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhoat:4200` so it becomes ` Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhoat:4200` also there is error in spelling, you are using localhoat not localhost

Comment: Yes, this error spelling was corrected before. Thanks